# jQuery Ajax call from SquareSpace forms

Tags: jquery, forms, squarespace, submission

I need to populate a third party app through all my SquareSpace website's form submissions. The app has given me a jQuery call so I've loaded jQuery into Code Injection > Header but I'm trying the code that the app supplied and it is not working. I have the token inserted, just blanked it out for the public.

I've also tried coding a trigger to the 'submit' button, but that hasn't worked either. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({    url: 'https://secure.zolasuite.com/api2/CRM/CreateExternalLead/',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    input: {
        'Token': '______',
        'FirstName': 'Derek',
        'LastName': 'Jeter',
        'Email': 'derek@aol.com',
        'Phone': '123-567-6780',
    }
```

})

Comment: can you check the browser devtools in the network tab to make sure your ajax call is actually being triggered?

Comment: No I don't think it is... It just appears as code at the bottom (it's injected into the footer).

Comment: is the ajax included in a script tag or similar? or is it just placed there?

Comment: It's in a script tag, which I needed to adjust. Now the code disappeared from the webpage, but I still don't see it in the Network tab.